# Boundedness of a linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove the following result.

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb K$. If $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is a linear functional such that $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ implies in the sequence $(f(x_n))$ being bounded, then the functional $f$ is bounded.

What I have done: Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$. Since $x_n$ converges to $0$, there must be some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_n|| \leq ||x_{n_0}||, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, there must be a constant $M > 0$ such that $||f(x_n)|| \leq M , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $||x_{n_0}|| \geq M$ then the result follows, but I am stuck in the case $||x_{n_0}|| < M$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to prove by contradiction, ie, suppose that f is not bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is unbounded. You can then pick a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ such that $\|x_n\| = 1$ but $|f(x_n)| \ge n^2$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Consider $y_n  := \frac{x_n}n$. Then $y_n \to 0$ but $|f(y_n)| \ge n$ which contradicts your assumption.

Comment: Yup. Seems to work. Thank you.